# Can I bake bread in a cast iron Dutch oven with the lid on, or should I use tin foil instead?

Tags: baking, bread, cast-iron

I have a Cuisinart cast iron enamelware dutch oven that I purchased recently to bake bread in the oven.  I am supposed to bake at 450 degrees.  The pot states it can be baked up to 500 degrees, however does that include the lid.  The lid is cast iron but has a knob on it that I am unsure of. Please send me info as my bread is rising and needs to be baked.  Should I just cover it with foil?  I don't think I will get the same results.

Comment: When baking I use either my seasoned bare iron ditch over, OR I use my le cruesset without the lid.

Comment: Do you have another lid that would roughly fit the pot and is oven safe?  If not, foil is probably okay.  (Many people have done this.)  The main reason to bake bread in a covered pot is to keep the steam in, which improves crust.  As long as you keep *most* of the steam in, the effect should be similar.  You don't really need a "tight seal."

Comment: Do you know which model/line your dutch oven is?

Comment: Is it one of these? http://www.cuisinart.com/products/cookware/castlite_nonstick_cast_iron/cil4525-26bb.html That's the only cast iron dutch oven I found on their site.

Comment: Based on putting things w/ plastic handles in the oven in the past ... if they can't take the heat, you'll know it both because of the smell, and the surface of the handle will change.  (it went from shiny to dull ... it looks like there are lots of tiny pock marks in the surface).  I suspect that most cast iron knobs could be changed out w/ all metal drawer-pulls, but then it'll be less comfortable to use stove-top (as it'd be heat conducting).

Comment: @Jefromi, there is also this thing: http://www.cuisinart.com/products/cookware/EnameledCastIron/ci670-30cr.html And though, their website doesn't list other products, google does: https://www.google.ca/search?q=cuisinart+dutch+oven&tbm=isch&imgil=zIMZB6ywK8hT_M%253A%253BOx-VZbmusAym2M%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fgreedymonster.wordpress.com%25252F2011%25252F09%25252F03%25252Fle-creuset-or-cuisinart%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=zIMZB6ywK8hT_M%253A%252COx-VZbmusAym2M%252C_&biw=2122&bih=1187&dpr=0.9&usg=__yI6anAt4vUdCT1jDbPsGSXnYjN0%3D#imgrc=isV2i-zlj06e5M%3A&usg=__yI6anAt4vUdCT1jDbPsGSXnYjN0%3D

Answer (score 2):

Presuming the Cuisinart knob is made of the same material as the Le Creuset one (Phenolic), [the given maximum temperature is 375°F](http://www.lecreuset.com/classic-phenolic-knob).

However, many people [(including this thorough article](http://www.notmartha.org/archives/2007/03/23/everything-i-know-about-dutch-ovens/)) recommend covering it with foil to protect it at higher temperatures. Also, I would suspect that giving 375°F as the limit means that it's OK to go higher, just not too often, and also they won't guarantee it above that temperature.

Comment: Le Creuset has more than one kind of knob: "The black phenolic lid knobs on our Signature range of enameled cast iron are heat-resistant to 480°F / 250°C. The black phenolic lid knobs on our Classic range of enameled cast iron are heat-resistant to 375°F / 190°C. Products with integral cast iron handles or stainless steel knobs can be used at any oven temperature. Pans with wooden handles or knobs must not be placed in the oven." (http://www.lecreuset.com/care-and-use/#ci-oven)